# Android findViewById() in Custom View

Tags: android, android-layout, view, custom-attributes, findviewbyid

I've written my custom View and i want to update some other views after interacting with my custom view.

**Main Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/display_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:tag="name"
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/id_number"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/display_name"/>

    <ge.altasoft.custom_views.IdNumber
        android:id="@+id/custom_id_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/id_number"
        android:paddingLeft="35dip"
        custom:firstName="@id/display_name"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Custom View Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/id_number_custom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:paddingRight="35dip" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/load_data_button"
        android:layout_width="30dip"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/load_data"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/id_number_custom" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Custom View Class, constructor and listener:**

```
 private int firstNameViewID;

public IdNumber (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initViews();

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.IdNumber);
        final int N = a.getIndexCount();
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            int attr = a.getIndex(i);
            switch(attr){
                case R.styleable.IdNumber_firstName:
                    firstNameViewID = a.getResourceId(attr, -1);
                    break;
            }
        }
        a.recycle();
    }



 private void initViews() {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.id_number_edit_text_custom, this, true);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.id_number_custom);
        loadButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.load_data_button);
        loadButton.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.INVISIBLE);
        loadData();
    }

private void loadData(){
        loadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText firstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.display_name);
                firstName.setText("Some Text");
            }
        });
    }
```

The Problem is that  `EditText firstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.display_name);` returns null. 
I know that just calling `findViewById()` will search the view in the layout that i inflated it.

If it's possible, how can I get the view of EditText with id: display_name from the main layout ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: no i don't want to get my custom view, i want to get other view from the mainLayout, with id diplay_name.

Comment: you are inflating xml but not storing the view returned. you can findview by id on that view.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
View Custmv;

 private void initViews() {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Custmv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.id_number_edit_text_custom, this, true);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.id_number_custom);
        loadButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.load_data_button);
        loadButton.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.INVISIBLE);
        loadData();
    }

private void loadData(){
        loadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText firstName = (EditText) Custmv.getParent().findViewById(R.id.display_name);
                firstName.setText("Some Text");
            }
        });
    }
```

try like this.

Comment: You didn't get it @Siddesh, 
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.id_number_custom);
loadButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.load_data_button);
this works fine, i can take views from the CustomView layout, I want to get Views from the MainLayout.

Comment: ok but why you want to handle main layout from custom view class?

Comment: because i want to update those views after interacting with my custom view.

Comment: i am not sure but try like this customview.this.getParent().findViewByID() in onclick listener

Comment: it won't work because parent of my customView will be null, as long as i'm inflating only the layout that customView represents.

Answer (score 3):

Change your Method as following and check it will work

```
private void initViews() {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.id_number_edit_text_custom, this, true);
    View view = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
    editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.id_number_custom);
    loadButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.load_data_button);
    loadButton.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.INVISIBLE);
    loadData();
}
```

Comment: I tried this Usman but it doesn't work, view is returning null.

Comment: There is no need to cast to View when LayoutInflater.inflate returns View.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

Inside customview constructor:

```
mContext = context;
```

Next inside customview you can call:

```
((MainActivity) mContext).updateText( text );
```

Inside `MainAcivity` define:

```
public void updateText(final String text) {

     TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
     txtView.setText(text);
}
```

It works for me.

Comment: calling `findViewById()` several times is bad and not efficient. If you are going to use it repeatedly, store a reference to it in a `final` field.

Answer (score 0):

If it's fixed layout you can do like that:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) IdNumber.this.getParent();
   EditText firstName = (EditText) parent.findViewById(R.id.display_name);
   firstName.setText("Some Text");
}
```

If you want find the EditText in flexible layout, I will help you later. Hope this help.

Comment: parent is null, as long as i'm inflating the layout that custom view represents.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ImageHolder holder = null;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ImageHolder();
        editText = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.id_number_custom);
        loadButton = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.load_data_button);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ImageHolder) row.getTag();
    }


    holder.editText.setText("Your Value");
    holder.loadButton.setImageBitmap("Your Bitmap Value");
    return row;
}
```

Comment: I think you're answering some other question here . . .

Comment: If you get error like null pointer than you make mistake in initialization of edittext and Imagebutton as per your code....

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your constructor

```
MainActivity maniActivity = (MainActivity)context;
EditText firstName = (EditText) maniActivity.findViewById(R.id.display_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

update View(context) -> View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.